# How I can hide row 'no-data' in datatable Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm beginner in vue and vuetify. I'm trying to make the first application on vue and vuetify. I'd like customize data table in vuetify. It has row 'no-data' default (with text 'No data available'). I want hide this row, but data table has no option such as 'hide-no-data'.

Answer (score 22):

You can override the `no-data` slot. Here is how it looks in the documentation:

> ```
> </v-data-table>    
>  <template slot="no-data">
>    <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
>      Sorry, nothing to display here :(
>    </v-alert>
>  </template>
> </v-data-table>
> ```

All you would have to do is replace the `v-alert` with an empty `div`

```
<template slot="no-data">
  <div></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is different. Even if I put an empty `div` in slot `no-data`, the row under the heading of the table remains, and I cannot remove it.

Comment: :hide-headers="nodata". change the nodata to false when there is no data.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
<v-data-table>
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
        Sorry, nothing to display here :(
      </v-alert>
    </template>
<v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but it might still help someone..

You can use an empty row and hide it by setting visibility to hidden:

```
<v-data-table ref="myTable">
    <template slot="no-data">
        <tr style="visibility: hidden;" />
    </template>
    ....
</v-data-table>
```

Or if you want the entire content gone you can remove it manually by code:

```
$refs.myTable.$el.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML = '';
```

Where `myTable` refers to the v-data-table.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the 'no-data' row via CSS

```
<style scoped>
    ::v-deep .v-data-table__empty-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that came to my mind was to go straight to the vDataTable component and change the message path to the vuetify component.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg8Uc.png)